# Tool/Application for visualize trajectories

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, graphics

I'm searching a tool for visualize trajectories like this:

[image: Dynamic-time-warping]

The picture shows the [Dynamic-time-warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) algorithm.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the solution by myself. I can use Matlab by giving the distance/dtw matrix of the DTW-Algorithm and use the surf method:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html